# Using the stack to remove vowels off a string but im getting the original string with vowels still on it

Tags: assembly, mips

im working on some code using mips that asks the user to wnter in a string, and remove the vowels from that string with the help of the Stack, this is what i have so far, sorry for the slight sloppiness as im fairly new to MIPS

```
    .text
    .globl main
    
    
main: 
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, prompt # prompt user for string
    syscall
    
    
    li  $v0, 8      # store string in str buffer
    la  $a0, str
    li  $a1, 120
    syscall
    
    
    
    li  $t4, 0
    li  $t1, 0
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -4    # push a NUL byte onto the stack to signal its bottom
    sw  $zero, ($sp)    # remember, always access the stact using words, not bytes!
    
loop:
    lbu $t0, str($t1)
    nop
    nop
    beqz    $t0, end
    nop
    nop
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1 #traverse through string until you reach the end of the string
    
    j   loop
    
    
end:

    addiu   $t1, -2     # backing up the index twice to start at the last character of string
    
loop2:  lbu $t0, str($t1)
    nop
    nop
    
    beq $t1, $t4, end2
    nop
    li  $t5, 'a'
    beq $t5, $t0, vowel     # picking up all of the consonants and putting them in the stack
    nop
    li  $t5, 'e'
    beq $t5, $t0, vowel
    nop
    li  $t5, 'i'
    beq $t5, $t0, vowel
    nop
    li  $t5, 'o'
    beq $t5, $t0, vowel
    nop
    li  $t5, 'u'
    beq $t5, $t0, vowel
    nop

    
vowel:  addiu   $t1, $t1, -1        # decrement index of string
    
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -4    # push
    sw  $t0, ($sp)
    nop
    j   loop2
    nop
    nop
end2:
    
    
    
    li  $t1, 0      # index of first byte of str buffer 
popl:   
    lw  $t0, ($sp)  # pop a char off the stack
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 4 # adjust $sp in load delay slot
    beqz    $t0, done   # NUL byte means empty stack
    nop         # branch delay slot
    sw  $t0, str($t1)   # store at string[$t1]
    nop
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1 # increment the index (in load delay slot)
    j   popl        # loop
    nop         # branch delay slot
                # print the reversed string
done:   li  $v0, 4      # print string service code
    la  $a0, str    # address of string
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 10     # exit program
    syscall

    
    
    
    
    
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
    
    
    .data
prompt: .asciiz "enter a word"
number: 

str:    .space   128
```

i feel like a lot of my issues are coming on how i store the individual characters in the stack as well as trying to pop them out back into the character buffer before the printing syscall. any guidance will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: `'b'`, `'c'`, and `'d'` aren't vowels, but you're missing `i`, `o`, and `u`.  But you're also not storing anywhere in `loop2:` so at best you're counting total vowels but not doing anything based on where each one is. Have you single-stepped this with a debugger to see registers, and follow the path of execution?   You wouldn't normally use the stack for this, except to reserve space for an array.  If you actually push and then pop one char at a time, that would also reverse the array.

Comment: oh shoot, i dont know how i forgot what vowels were but i edited the code and added in the pushing of the consonants. still getting an error when i start the popping of the stack and adding it to the stack buffer though. @PeterCordes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
popl:   
    lw  $t0, ($sp)  # pop a char off the stack
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 4 # adjust $sp in load delay slot
    beqz    $t0, done   # NUL byte means empty stack
    nop         # branch delay slot
    sw  $t0, str($t1)   # store at string[$t1]
    nop
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1 # increment the index (in load delay slot)
    j   popl        # loop
    nop         # branch delay slot
```

See the line `sw $t0, str($t1)`? That should be `sb $t0,str($t1)`. You're storing the desired letters as 32-bit words on the stack because you have to, as the stack needs to be word-aligned at all times. However, each character *in the string* takes up only one byte, so you need to use `sb` to store them into the string.

As an example, I'll show what happens if your code were run with the input string "BOOBOO".

This represents what happens on the first pass through:

```
popl:   
    lw  $t0, ($sp)        # $t0 = 0x00000042 (0x42 in ASCII = 'B')
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 4   # adjust $sp in load delay slot
    beqz    $t0, done     # NUL byte means empty stack
    nop                   # branch delay slot
    sw  $t0, str($t1)     # store at string[$t1]
    nop                   # load delay slot
```

After the store, we have the following:

```
str:
.word 0x00000042 #could be 0x42000000 depending on your CPU's endianness
.space 124
```

After storing we execute the following and loop again:

```
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1 # increment the index (in load delay slot)
    j   popl            # loop
    nop                 # branch delay slot
```

If you had used `sb $t0, str($t1)`, the `addiu $t1,$t1,1` wouldn't be a problem. But since you're using `sw`, you get an error. This is because `lw` and `sw` in MIPS *can only be used on addresses that are word-aligned,* i.e. their hex value ends in 0, 4, 8, or C. Failure to do so will result in an alignment fault. The statement `sw $t0, str($t1)` became unaligned when you executed `addiu   $t1, $t1, 1.`

---

*Side note: It's not a good practice to use labels as constant offsets like you have here. Reason being is that they can cause similar alignment faults if you store a string above them like so:*

```
foo: .asciiz "Hello"  #total of 6 bytes, so the array below is unaligned
bar: .space 128       #doing "sw $t1,bar($t0) would cause an alignment fault if $t0 = 0.
```